# Certification Requirements going from 5v to 220v

Tags: certification

We are considering developing a 220v/110v version of our electronic product that currently uses a 5v external power supply. Our 5v version has already been tested against the EU LVD but we are unsure if there are other/additional requirements.
We want to use an internal AC/DC module (220v to 5v) that is already certified but are not sure what impact it would have on the overall product certification.

What mandatory (and strongly recommended) certifications are required / what directives we would need to meet (especially for EU, US, and Australian markets)?

Comment: This really is a no-brainer. Buy a certified 220/110 to 5 V power supply. Preferrably an external one in a plug top. If it must go into your product package, then a module. There is so much to do to support testing and safety certification worldwide that you would have to be looking at millions of units before doing your own design even started to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to be completely under the low voltage directive, in EU. In the States there's probably some kind of UL you need to respect.

The *most* important things are grounding and insulation; so you should study clearance and creepage. Depending on the type of product (audio/video, household, machinery and so on) there could be additional requirements (for example hair driers have special requisites on the heating element).

As for the PCB design there are two major parts:

- Use correctly rated components *keeping in mind you overvoltage category*; for example even if 220VAC is only 315V peak you don't generally use 600V TRIACs, you (typically) need a 800V rating;
- Keep the correct spacing between traces and in some cases even components; see clearance and creepage above; it's not unusual to cut slots in the board to comply.

Since you already have a lab for LVD testing ask them for specific guidance. Also, if it's feasible, simply *buy* a pre-certified power supply and put it in the enclosure, it *really* semplifies the job.